# How do you configure Spring Cloud Sleuth kafka zipkin sender to reduce the retention period?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to set up so that when I deploy a new environment the `zipkin` Kafka topic used by  spring cloud sleuth zipkin sender would have a low retention period since it will get processed by something else or it will be ignored (on the developer machine).

I tried to add this

```
@Bean("zipkin")
public NewTopic zipkin() {

  return TopicBuilder.name("zipkin")
    .config(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(Duration.ofMinutes(2).getSeconds() * 1000))
    .compact()
    .replicas(1)
    .build();
}
```

but that didn't work because the topic is already created and the configured already.  I know I can do

```
kafka-configs --bootstrap-server $_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER --alter --topic zipkin --add-config retention.ms=2000
```

But I'd want it set up on the Spring application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring-Kafka does not provide an `AdminClient` in the application context so it needs to be built rather than having it autowirable for you.  The following code shows how to do it by creating the `AdminClient` using the bootstrap servers provided in the environment and setting multiple properties.

```
    /**
     * Retention time for zipkin messages.  Defaults to 2 minutes.
     */
    @Value("${zipkin.retention.ms:120000}")
    private long zipkinRetentionMs;

    /**
     * Segment bytes size for zipkin.  Defaults to 10MB.
     */
    @Value("${zipkin.segment.bytes:10485760}")
    private long zipkinSegmentBytes;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @PostConstruct
    public void fixZipkin() {

        try (final var adminClient = AdminClient.create(Map.of(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers))) {
            adminClient.incrementalAlterConfigs(
                Map.of(
                    new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.TOPIC, "zipkin"),
                    List.of(
                        new AlterConfigOp(
                            new ConfigEntry(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(zipkinRetentionMs)),
                            AlterConfigOp.OpType.SET
                        ),
                        new AlterConfigOp(
                            new ConfigEntry(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_BYTES_CONFIG, String.valueOf(zipkinSegmentBytes)),
                            AlterConfigOp.OpType.SET
                        )
                    )));
        } finally {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an AdminClient instance to modify existing topic configurations